# Having the same untracked file in 2 different branches in Git?

Tags: git

I'm beginning with git and i'm having some trouble to find out a good solution for my problem.

I have 2 branches : Prod and Test, which both allow me deploy my application on 2 different environments. I'd like to both have the same **config file** but with a different content.

Like I found in similar posts I though to keep this file in the gitignore but i can't change to one of the branch to the other with this solution.

The only solution i find would be to commit this file in both branches and then add it to the gitignore, is it a bad practice ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having different branches for prod and test can be troublesome and doesn't really make much sense. Conventionally branches are used for fixes/new features which can be merged with the master(main) branch after we are sure that this new fix/feature works and also doesn't cause any side effects (i.e. all the tests are passing) in the application.

So to be able to run tests you will have to merge the same feature to your test branch and then once they pass those tests merge it to your prod branch. You will also have to revert the test branch in case your tests fail so it's in sync with the prod branch at all times.

Alternatively, you can have both the config in the same branch ie (master) and let your application handle wether your test config or prod config should be used based on the **environment variable** you've set. It is also recommended that you gitignore your prod config as it may in certain cases contain secrets like API keys and client ids.

So as for having the same [named] config file I'd say you rather do something like config.dev, config.test, config.prod (gitingnore).

Also learn about git-flow which is an industry-standard and used by many. (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different versions of the same file across different branches, then simply commit one version on one branch, say `master`, then create a new branch off of `master`, `topic`, for example. Then, checkout `topic` and edit it all you like without affecting the version on `master`.